# Moment of inertia for a triangle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

First, I fully admit this is one of the physics problems that we have as a homework. However, I am totally clueless how I am supposed to solve this. I do have an answer that I am supposed to get, but I have no idea HOW I am supposed to get it.

Basically, we have following picture:

[image: Image of the situation]

And the problem is that I am supposed to calculate the moment of inertia in relation to z axis. The mass of the triangle is $M$.

The outcome is, according the official info, $(1/6)Ma^2$ and reading from the material, I fail to see how this is achieved.

I am not asking detailed answer(though one would be nice). Just something to get me started with this problem. Something I could take and try to apply to get the right answer. I would prefer to come to the solution myself, but at the moment I am struck and I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Hint, work out the equation that describes the edge in the z-y plane

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? What have you got so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment of inertia (with the x-axis as the axis of rotation): $I_x = \int (y^2+z^2) \rho dv$

Density $\rho$ is constant, volume element is $dv = dydzdx$. The integral over $x$ is simply the thickness $t$ of the triangle. Clearly it holds: $M= \rho t \frac{ab}{2}$.

Integration interval: $z \in [0,b - \frac{b}{a}y], y \in [0,a]$ (the z-interval depends on the Location on the y-axis; it has the Maximum on $y=0$ and decreases linearily with $y$ until it has reached $y=a$). Hence:

$I_x = \rho t \int_0^a \int_0^{b - \frac{b}{a}y} (y^2+z^2) dz dy = \rho t \int_0^a [\frac{z^3}{3}+y^2z]_0^{b - \frac{b}{a}y} dy$

Comment: Around the z axis

Comment: What Chris2807 said, it's supposed to in relation to z-axis. Also, like I said in the post, I got the correct answer, i just need a nudge to get to it.

Comment: @kryomaxim  the rule in this site is that you don't solve the user's exercise but give him hints, s.t. he solves alone. This is why someone here gave you a minus as a warning not to do this a second time. Look how proceeds Chris2807. And, regretfully, you disturbed. Obviously you were well intended, but the best thing is that the user learn to solve his exercises by himself.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to calculate
$$
\int_A dA r^2 \sigma  = \int_0^a dy \int_0^{b\left(1-y/a\right)} dz \ y^2 \sigma\left(y,z\right)
$$
where $r = y$ is the distance of the differential mass $\sigma\left(y,z\right) dy dz$ from the $z$ axis, and $\sigma\left(y,z\right) = 2 M / \left(ab\right)$ is the (constant) mass density of the triangle.